# How to Join Wav files in One Using C#

Tags: c#, audio, combiners

I create a software to concatenate wav files into one
I use this code

```
using Alvas.Audio;    
private void JoinWav()
{
    string[] files = new string[] { "file01_01.wav","file01_01.wav"};
    AudioCompressionManager.Join("res.wav", files);
}
```

It's working for me ,but i use trial of  Alvas.Audio 
is there a way to create something like this free?

Comment: Yes. (1) Learn about bytes reading / writing. (2) Keep first wav file's header and remove the headers of any following (next) joined files. (3) Adjust "Duration" in the (one and only) kept header to match length.

Comment: Alternatively look for FFmpeg.exe and run as process. There are tutorials to pass commands to it (including concatenate a/vfiel formats)